# Use store a view in stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a java code that use a stored procedure for that it is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Rent]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    select * from SearchRent    
END
```

and `SearchRent` is a view in `sql server`

```
SELECT     dbo.Tbl_Software.ID AS SotwareID, dbo.Tbl_Software.UserID_Rent, dbo.Tbl_Software.Name AS SoftwareName, dbo.Tbl_User.Family, 
                      dbo.Tbl_User.Name AS UserName, dbo.Tbl_User.Tel, dbo.Tbl_Software.DataStart, dbo.Tbl_Software.DataFinish, dbo.Tbl_Software.ID_Category
FROM         dbo.Tbl_Software INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Tbl_User ON dbo.Tbl_Software.UserID_Rent = dbo.Tbl_User.ID
```

and my java code is:

```
public class frmRented extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form frmRented */
    public frmRented() {
        initComponents();
        MyTools.SetCenterLocation(this);
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        try {
            da.Connect();

            //da.rs = da.st.executeQuery("select * from SearchRent");
            //da.rs = da.st.executeQuery("{call Search_Rent()}");
            CallableStatement cal = da.con.prepareCall("{call Search_Rent()}",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            da.rs = cal.executeQuery();

            da.rs.last();
            int rc = da.rs.getRow();
            da.rs.beforeFirst();
            int cc = 9;

            String[] header = {"id", "idc", "name", "preamble", "k ", "s", "d", "a","e"};
            String[][] data = new String[rc][cc];
            int i = 0;

            while (da.rs.next()) {
                data[i][0] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_Software.ID");
                data[i][1] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_Software.ID_Category");
                data[i][2] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_Software.Name");
                data[i][3] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_Software.UserID_Rent");
                data[i][4] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_User.Name");
                data[i][5] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_User.Family");
                data[i][6] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_User.Tel");
                data[i][7] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_Software.DataStart");
                data[i][8] = da.rs.getString("Tbl_Software.DataFinish");
                i++;

            }
            jTable1 = new JTable(data, header);
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
            cal.close();
            da.Disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

but when I execute this code I have this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name Tbl_Sofware.ID is not valid.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace, or tell us what line is throwing the error? I'd assume it is the call to beforeFirst, but more information would be good.

Comment: Change `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` to `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not properly declared. Try to run SELECT statement from view in sole manner, and when you succeed, wrap the resulting statement with view.

**OR**

you need not specify the table alias while reading values thru reader, replace your code with this in appropriate manner **AND** you have to refer real column names from your view:

```
data[i][0] = da.rs.getString("SotwareID");
data[i][1] = da.rs.getString("ID_Category");
data[i][2] = da.rs.getString("SoftwareName");
data[i][3] = da.rs.getString("UserID_Rent");
data[i][4] = da.rs.getString("UserName");
data[i][5] = da.rs.getString("Family");
data[i][6] = da.rs.getString("Tel");
data[i][7] = da.rs.getString("DataStart");
data[i][8] = da.rs.getString("DataFinish");
```

Comment: this code too have same exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name ID is not valid.

Comment: Sorry, not mentioned the real names of columns in view. Updated answer.

Comment: ooohhhh,com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name SoftwareID is not valid.

Comment: Be careful - your column name if SotwareID - without a **f** letter!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
CallableStatement cal = da.con.prepareCall("{call Search_Rent()}",);
```

With

```
CallableStatement cal = da.con.prepareCall("{call Search_Rent()}",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

I think you need this because this line

```
da.st = da.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Isn't doing anything, you create this `Statement`, and assign it to `da.st` but then don't use it. You actually execute your query using the `CallableStatement`